# Why is [object HTMLCollection] being displayed instead of the element I created?

Tags: javascript, html, object, dom, htmlcollection

In Javascript I am attempting to make a new div. This is what I added to make the div.

```
html+= "<div>" + concerts + "</div>";
```

but in my browser it displays [object HTMLCollection] where the div tag should be.

concerts is a pre defined var.

Can anyone explain to me what I might be missing to make this work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you adding the `html` element to the DOM?

Comment: var html = ""; document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = html;

Comment: Because you have a collection of DOM nodes, not a string of HTML.

Answer (score 5):

`concerts` is apparently a collection of elements, such as the one you get from `getElementsByTagName` and similar. When you do

```
"<div>" + concerts + "</div>"
```

...you implicitly call `toString` on it, and so you get that `"[object HTMLElementCollection]"` string.

If you want to put all the elements in the collection in a div, and then add that div to the page, you can't use string concat:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
Array.prototype.slice.call(concerts).forEach(concerts, function(concert) {
    div.appendChild(concert);
});
document.body.appendChild(div); // Or wherever you want to add the div
```

The `Array.prototype.slice.call(concerts)` part of that converts the HTMLElementCollection into a true array, then we use `forEach` on that array to loop through and move the elemnts in to the `div.` ([This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) goes into that in more detail.) (We need the `slice` part of that, because HTMLElementCollections are typically **live** collections, and so moving the first element into the div takes it out of the collection, which messes up the `forEach`.)

This example starts out with four paragraphs that aren't in a div. Then when you press the button, it creates a div with padding and a border, and moves the paragraphs into it:

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
    var concerts = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = "foo";
    Array.prototype.slice.call(concerts).forEach(function(concert) {
        div.appendChild(concert);
    });
    document.body.appendChild(div); // Or wherever you want to add the div
};
```

```css
.foo {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
<p>Paragraph 4</p>
<button type="button">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I couldn't get this to work with my code unfortunately

Comment: @GemmaJ: If you can't get it working with your code, boil that attempt down to an [MCVE](/help/mcve) (ideally using Stack Snippets -- the `<>` button -- so it's runnable) and post it as a question. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

`html` must be an object. When you try to add something to an object it turns it into a string making it look like [object]. You probably don't want to just `+=` but instead use a method on the DOM api to insert concerts (`appendChild` for example could work if you made some changes)

Answer (score 0):

Using `+=` you are adding an object, seemingly a collection of elements,  to a string, causing the implicit call to its `toString()` method. So you get `[object HTMLCollection]`.

Comment: I tried this but I still got [object HTMLCollection] in my browser